# Can't install cmake - Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to install `cmake` and `rugged` gems. My Ruby is 193 and my DevKit is installed correspondingly to this version. I modified the system `PATH` and installed DevKit.

Now I try to run `gem install cmake`, and I'm getting an error:

```
> gem install cmake
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cmake:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:5:in `chdir': No such file or directory - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/
OENT)
        from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cmake-2.8.7 for in
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cmake-2.8.7/ext/cmake/gem_make.out
```

I don't know what to do, I used newer Ruby earlier and the problem was the same. What can I do?

Comment: Did you get this working in the end? I'm having the same problem now

Comment: Three years ago, huh? But probably not, because if I did, I would write an answer :)

Comment: I actually got it working! I just posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

I installed it by downloading the [installer](https://cmake.org/download/), and then installing through the UI. For my purposes, I needed to make sure that the box was checked which added the variables to my PATH.